# Ionic, Angular, Mapbox omnivore not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, mapbox

I use Mapbox, AngularJS, and Ionic framework; here is my controller:

```
//using omnivore to add marker in csv file 
var restroom_marker_layer = omnivore.csv('/lib/airports3.csv', null, L.mapbox.featureLayer().on('ready',function(e){
  var clusterGroup = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
  e.target.eachLayer(function(layer) {
      var cluster_marker = clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);
      restroom_marker.push(layer._latlng);
      layer.bindPopup('<button class="button button-icon ion-ios-star-outline rate"></button><button class="button button-icon ion-ios-star-outline rate"></button><button class="button button-icon ion-ios-star-outline rate"></button><button class="button button-icon ion-ios-star-outline rate"></button><button class="button button-icon ion-ios-star-outline rate"></button><br/><button class="button button-outline button-positive departure_point" value="' + layer._latlng.lng + ',' + layer._latlng.lat + '">출발</button><br/><button class="button button-outline button-assertive destination_point" value="' + layer._latlng.lng + ',' + layer._latlng.lat + '">도착</button><br/><button class="button button-outline button-royal evaluation" value="' + layer._latlng.lng + ',' + layer._latlng.lat + '">평가</button>',{closeButton: false});
  });
  map.addLayer(clusterGroup);
}));
```

this works fine in web browsers, but it is not working in iOS and marker not added.

error message here

```
restroom_prj[22202:1332450] error JSON.stringify()ing argument: TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.
```

How can I resolve these issue?